# How to disable (or redirect) logging on an AWS Step Function that calls parallel Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm running an AWS step function with parallel execution branches.

Each branch succeeds individually, however the overall function fails with the following error:

**States.DataLimitExceeded - The state/task returned a result with a size exceeding the maximum number of characters service limit.**

I then found an article from AWS that describes this issue and suggests a work around:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html

That article says:

**The Lambda invoke API includes logs in the response by default. Multiple Lambda invocations in a workflow can trigger States.DataLimitExceeded errors. To avoid this, include "LogType" = "None" as a parameter when you invoke your Lambda functions.**

My question is where *exactly* do I put it? I've tried putting it various places in the state machine definition, however I get the following error:

**The field 'LogType' is not supported by Step Functions**

That error seems contrary to the support article, so perhaps I'm doing it wrong!

Any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Cheers

**UPDATE 1 :** 
To be clear, this is a parallel function, with 26 parallel branches. Each branch has a small output as per the example below. The biggest item in this data is the LogResult, which (when base64 decoded) is just the billing info. I think this info multiplied by 26 has led to the error, so I just want to turn this LogResult off!!!

```
{
  "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST",
  "LogResult": "U1RBUlQgUmVxdWVzdElkOiBlODJjZTRkOS0zMjk2LTRlNDctYjcyZC1iYmEwMzI1YmM3MGUgVmVyc2lvbjogJExBVEVTVApFTkQgUmVxdWVzdElkOiBlODJjZTRkOS0zMjk2LTRlNDctYjcyZC1iYmEwMzI1YmM3MGUKUkVQT1JUIFJlcXVlc3RJZDogZTgyY2U0ZDktMzI5Ni00ZTQ3LWI3MmQtYmJhMDMyNWJjNzBlCUR1cmF0aW9uOiA3NzI5Ljc2IG1zCUJpbGxlZCBEdXJhdGlvbjogNzgwMCBtcwlNZW1vcnkgU2l6ZTogMTAyNCBNQglNYXggTWVtb3J5IFVzZWQ6IDEwNCBNQglJbml0IER1cmF0aW9uOiAxMTY0Ljc3IG1zCQo=",
  "Payload": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": {
      "signs": 63,
      "nil": ""
    }
  },
  "SdkHttpMetadata": {
    "HttpHeaders": {
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "53",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Date": "Thu, 21 Nov 2019 04:00:42 GMT",
      "X-Amz-Executed-Version": "$LATEST",
      "X-Amz-Log-Result": "U1RBUlQgUmVxdWVzdElkOiBlODJjZTRkOS0zMjk2LTRlNDctYjcyZC1iYmEwMzI1YmM3MGUgVmVyc2lvbjogJExBVEVTVApFTkQgUmVxdWVzdElkOiBlODJjZTRkOS0zMjk2LTRlNDctYjcyZC1iYmEwMzI1YmM3MGUKUkVQT1JUIFJlcXVlc3RJZDogZTgyY2U0ZDktMzI5Ni00ZTQ3LWI3MmQtYmJhMDMyNWJjNzBlCUR1cmF0aW9uOiA3NzI5Ljc2IG1zCUJpbGxlZCBEdXJhdGlvbjogNzgwMCBtcwlNZW1vcnkgU2l6ZTogMTAyNCBNQglNYXggTWVtb3J5IFVzZWQ6IDEwNCBNQglJbml0IER1cmF0aW9uOiAxMTY0Ljc3IG1zCQo=",
      "x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length": "0",
      "x-amzn-RequestId": "e82ce4d9-3296-4e47-b72d-bba0325bc70e",
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "root=1-5dd60be1-47c4669ce54d5208b92b52a4;sampled=0"
    },
    "HttpStatusCode": 200
  },
  "SdkResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "e82ce4d9-3296-4e47-b72d-bba0325bc70e"
  },
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html is where a lambda invocation api can take the logging parameter.   You're not invoking that directly though

Comment: As a side note, the output of the python scripts called by the step functions print nothing. I don't really care about the output, just a success/fail error code. I simply need a way to prevent this error. I suspect the small output of the combined parallel executions is what's causing the problem so really just need to redirect the output to S3 maybe?   Here's the specific error again {
  "error": "States.DataLimitExceeded",
  "cause": "The state/task 'Get Bays' returned a result with a size exceeding the maximum number of characters service limit."
}

Comment: @Timbo I hit the same issue. I just copied most of your initial question to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=313708

Answer (score 4):

I ran into exactly the same problem as you recently.  You haven't said what your lambdas are doing or returning however I found that AWS refers to limits that tasks have within executions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html#service-limits-task-executions.

What I found was that my particular lambda had an extremely long response with 10s of thousands of characters.  Amending that so that the response from the lambda was more reasonable got past the error in the step function.

Comment: Hmm the responses to the individual lambda calls are not very big, but there are a lot of calls so I suppose putting them together is what breaks things. If only I knew where "LogType" = "None" was supposed to go!

Comment: Perhaps including some more info regarding what the step function is doing a the point that it errors, and in the run up to the error could help us understand what's happening.

Comment: Hi Mike, each branch succeeds individually, however the overall function fails. Each branch is just getting some data form an api and putting it in dynamo db

Comment: Specifically, the log shows ParallelStateSucceeded then ExecutionFailed, then {
  "error": "States.DataLimitExceeded",
  "cause": "The state/task 'Get Bays' returned a result with a size exceeding the maximum number of characters service limit."
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem a week ago.
I way I solved is like below:

You can define which portion of the result that is transmitted to the next step.

For that you have to use

"OutputPath": "$.part2",

In your json input you have

"part1": {
    "portion1": {
      "procedure": "Delete_X"
    },
    "portion2":{
      "procedure": "Load_X" 
    }
 },

"part2": {
    "portion1": {
      "procedure": "Delete_Y"
    },
    "portion2":{
      "procedure": "Load_Y" 
    }
 }

Once part1 is processed, you make sure that part1 is not sent in the output and the resultpath related to it. Just part 2 which is needed for the following steps is sent for the next steps.
With this: "OutputPath": "$.part2",

let me know if that helps

Comment: Hmm I think this is getting close to the answer, however I haven't been able to make it work yet.  I understand that the $ represents the returning JSON and that $.part2 would mean that a part2 needs to exist in the JSON.  In my example I tried setting "OutputPath": "$.Payload.statusCode" (since this exists in my returning json) however still have the same issues. I'd love to be able to set the output to just "OutputPath": null but this doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I handle large data in my Step Functions by storing the result in an S3 bucket, and then having my State Machine return the path to the result-file (and a brief summary of the data or a status like PASS/FAIL).

The same could be done using a DB if that's more comfortable.

This way won't have to modify your results' current format, you can just pass the reference around instead of a huge amount of data, and they are persisted as long as you'd like to have them.

The start of the Lambdas looks something like this to figure out if the input is from a file or plain data:

```
    bucket_name = util.env('BUCKET_NAME')
    if 'result_path' in input_data.keys():
        # Results are in a file that is referenced.
        try: 
            result_path = input_data['result_path']
            result_data = util.get_file_content(result_path, bucket_name)
        except Exception as e:
            report.append(f'Failed to parse JSON from {result_path}: {e}')
    else:
        # Results are just raw data, not a reference.
        result_data = input_data
```

Then at the end of the Lambda they will upload their results and return directions to that file:

```
    import boto3
    def upload_results_to_s3(bucket_name, filename, result_data_to_upload):
    try:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        results_prefix = 'Path/In/S3/'
        results_suffix = '_Results.json'

        result_file_path = '' + results_prefix + filename + results_suffix

        s3.Object(bucket_name, result_file_path).put(
            Body=(bytes(json.dumps(result_data_to_upload, indent=2).encode('UTF-8')))
        )

        return result_file_path



    result_path = upload_results_to_s3(bucket_name, filename, result_data_to_upload)

    result_obj = {
        "result_path": result_path,
        "bucket_name": bucket_name
    }
    return result_obj
```

Then the next Lambda will have the first code snippet in it, in order to get the input from the file.

The Step Function Nodes look like this, where the Result will be result_obj in the python code above:

```
    "YOUR STATE": 
    { 
        "Comment": "Call Lambda that puts results in file", 
        "Type": "Task", 
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:YOUR LAMBDA ARN", 
        "InputPath": "$.next_function_input", 
        "ResultPath": "$.next_function_input", 
        "Next": "YOUR-NEXT-STATE" 
    }
```

Comment: This sounds great, what's the syntax of this? i.e. do you have an example JSON you could give?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on the same issue. Step function imposes a limit of 32,768 characters on the data that can be passed around between two states.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html

Maybe you need to think and breakdown your problem in a different way? That's what I did. Because removing the log response would give you some elasticity but your solution will not scale after a certain limit.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is, add "emptyOutputPath": "" to your json,

```
"emptyOutputPath": "",

"part1": { "portion1": { "procedure": "Delete_X"
}, "portion2":{ "procedure": "Load_X" } },

"part2": { "portion1": { "procedure": "Delete_Y"
}, "portion2":{ "procedure": "Load_Y" } }
```

That will allow you to do "OutputPath":"$.emptyOutputPath" which is empty and will clear ResultPath.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is a good idea and I think it should have worked however I had no luck with this unfortunately. Will keep troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0):

Just following up on this issue to close the loop.

I basically gave up on using parallel lambdas in favour of using AQS message queues instead